# Estimating Coefficients of Multiple Regression

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression

I have the following problem:

I'm using the data "Railtrail" from this library "mosaicData". 
I already have the coeffiecient of this following linear regression model : 
`lm(volume ~ hightemp + cloudcover + weekday, data = RailTrail)` , compute for the population.

Now, I need to estimate the coeffiecient of that model with samples and to build a confidence interval (95%). 
So I need to compute all the coefficients of the data samples previously generated. I was asked to use a loop 'for' but I don't know how to compute the LR models. I also need to store the coefficient obtained.

I tried to do it doing this

```
trial <- list()
set.seed(101)

for(i in 1:100){
  trial[[i]] <- RailTrail %>% 
    lm(volume ~ hightemp + cloudcover + weekday, data = RailTrail)
}
```

but I get the following error:

**Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'language'**

Thank you,

Don't hesitate to ask further precision if my request is not clear.

Francisco

Comment: There's no need to use `RailTrail %>% ` here since you are using `data=RailTrail` in the `lm()` call. The pipe assumes that you are passing the value into the first parameter for the following function but `lm` expects a formula in the first parameter. Just use `trial[[i]] <-lm(volume ~ hightemp + cloudcover + weekday, data = RailTrail)` Though you will get the same answer every time so I'm not sure why you are looping here.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why you are doing a for loop. You can just use the `predict()` function if you want to produce a confidence interval for each observation.

Comment: Maybe this [CrossValidated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/316483/manually-bootstrapping-linear-regression-in-r) or [this](https://rdrr.io/cran/car/man/Boot.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the confidence interval for the model parameters? If so, this example I hope illustrates a succinct way of doing so:

```r
model <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + gear, data = mtcars)
bind_cols(broom::tidy(model), broom::confint_tidy(model))
```